# how to change background color of menu using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to change the background color of my menu and still get the same result.
I want to set my menu to white background.
my menu looks like that

```
<item

    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:icon="@drawable/exit"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="exit">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:icon="@drawable/get_info"
    android:title="about">
</item>
```

and my style looks like that

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

</resources>
```

and the code is:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.submenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and I want that my menu background will be white and not as default of android style.

Comment: are you asking about the background color of the `ActionBar` or the `Menu` that appears at the bottom of the screen after one clicked the menu key?

Answer (score 0):

change the actionBar background like this:

```
View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom_view, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Comment: where I set the wanted color? and where I need to add this code?

Comment: set the wanted color inside the layout, create your custom layout as you wish, add this code in onCreate

Comment: but it menu pop up and not  layout of an activity gui.